# csv.Error: did you open the file in text mode?

Tags: python, csv, urllib

the python file contains the following code

```
import csv 
import urllib.request
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aparrish/cb1672e98057ea2ab7a1/raw/13166792e0e8436221ef85d2a655f1965c400f75/lebron_james.csv"
stats = list(csv.reader(urllib.request.urlopen(url)))
```

When I run the above code in python, I get the following exception:

> Error
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aparrish/cb1672e98057ea2ab7a1/raw/13166792e0e8436221ef85d2a655f1965c400f75/lebron_james.csv"
>   ----> 2 stats = list(csv.reader(urllib.request.urlopen(url)))
>
> Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `urllib` recommends using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.

You must pay attention to two things:

- you must decode the data you receive from the internet (which is bytes) in order to have text. With `requests`, using `text` takes care of the decoding.
- `csvreader` expects a list of lines, not a block of text. Here, we split it with `splitlines`.

So, you can do it like this:

```
import csv 
import requests

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aparrish/cb1672e98057ea2ab7a1/raw/13166792e0e8436221ef85d2a655f1965c400f75/lebron_james.csv"

text = requests.get(url).text
lines = text.splitlines()
stats = csv.reader(lines)

for row in stats:
    print(row)

# ['Rk', 'G', 'Date', 'Age', 'Tm', ...]
# ['1', '1', '2013-10-29', '28-303', 'MIA',... ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what is that data, but if you interested in separating them with `,`, you can try something like this:

```
stats = list(csv.reader(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()))
```

> 1.It reads from response data
>
> 2.Decode from Bytes to String
>
> 3.CSV reader
>
> 4.Cast CSV object to list

let me know if you want that data somehow differently so i can edit my answer.
 Good Luck.

Comment: It's statistics for LeBron James' first five games of the 2013-2014 NBA season. The source of the data: https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01/gamelog/2014/

Comment: @SzuyuChen so how do you want it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the response of `urllib.request.urlopen`.

```
stats = list(csv.reader(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("UTF-8")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
import csv
import io
import urllib.request
csv_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lst = list(csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(csv_response)))
```